# Symfony 3, cache:clear error connection timeout

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, console

On server i am trying clear cache but after run this command (`php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`) a get error:

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]
>     An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out
>
> [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out
>
> [PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out

Database credentials are in `parameters.yaml` and connection to db is working... Whole web is working...

Can anybody give me some hints/direction? Thx.

Comment: Is it possible that you store some cache in a database using another configuration than the one in the parameters file ? Try running the clear cache command with `-vvv` option in order to see which file try to connect to the db

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the cache manually, see if that solves the issue.It should be

`rm -rf var/cache/prod`

Also try connecting to the database from your prod, through console to make sure there is nothing wrong with connectivity.
Thanks!